# How do I make a modal in the center of the screen about a third of the area? Mediaquery also possible?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, video, media-queries, bootstrap-modal

I have the following code and it works well for bringing a 350px modal video to the screen, but I'd prefer it to be larger and centered. Is this a bootstrap issue? Also, I'd prefer is the modal didn't have a white background... A bit stuck. I'd also like to mediaquery this property to take up almost the whole screen for mobile...

HTML -

```
<a href=""
   data-toggle="modal"
   data-target="#videoModal"
   data-theVideo="http://www.youtube.com/embed/loFtozxZG0s">
   <div class="trailer_button">
       <i class="fa fa-play"></i>  Watch Trailer
   </div>
</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="videoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="videoModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <div>
          <iframe width="100%" height="350"  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tBYm53L79YY"></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: It would be useful for you to create and link to a JSFiddle - we can then play with your code with ease!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
iframe{  
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```